# run terminal commands in custom atom package

Tags: javascript, shell, atom-editor

I am currently creating an atom package which runs commands on the windows command prompt **not** the atom command prompt. So far, I only have the code:

```
if (editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()){
  let editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
  let file = editor.buffer.file;
  let path = file.path;

  editor.save();

  editor.insertText(path);
}
```

I do not know how to spawn a command window or how to run a command. All that code does is check if the user is in a text window and then for testing purposes inserts the path into the text window. Eventually, I am going to need to run `cd path`.

Comment: Do you want to run a command or do you want a command prompt to open and then run the command?

Comment: Either one, the ultimate goal to run the java compilation command, so if it is possible to run a command without having to make the command prompt visible, that is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a program, you can use the with [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module that's bundled with Node (Atom has its own wrapper for it, see [`BufferedProcess`](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/BufferedProcess))

**Example:**

```
// Somewhere in your header
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Where you need to execute the Java compiler
const javac = spawn('javac', [path], {stdio: inherit});
```

For debugging purposes, you probably want to use something like [console-panel](https://atom.io/packages/console-panel) to print messages.